# Running podman on a RedHat AL9 server issues

Tags: docker-compose, podman, redhat-containers, almalinux, podman-compose

I am experiencing difficulties with Podman builds on an NFS-mounted directory. The error message indicates a problem with the lsetxattr operation, which suggests that the NFS filesystem does not support extended attributes required by Podman. I’ve been running this same application in an NSF area on a SL7 server and docker for the last 6 months and never faced this issue before, but it keeps appearing now that we shifted to podman on AL9.

[Sample of the error I get when running a simple podman script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJYx9.png)

I was able to run my dockerized app using podman only when: 1) Moved the app folder to /scratch area that is mounted on XFS, 2) switch to root using the ksu command, and 3) run “podman-compose up –build” using sudo in front.

However, I need to run this on the original NFS area.

Comment: This was fixed by the following: Podman has issues running on a NFS storage. The config file (/etc/containers/storage.conf) was modified to allow rootless runs. Containers are now stored out of the NFS area on /var due to issues with the NFS file system.

Changes made:
rootless_storage_path = "/var/lib/user/$USER/containers/storage"